# Only canvas.create_rectangle is shown

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tkinter, linux-mint

I run Linux Mint 16.2.
I have a Samsung laptop AMD 64

When i use in Python 3.5 the command: `canvas.create_rectangle(x1,x2,y1,y2)`, everything goes fine, but when I use `canvas.create_oval(x1,x2,y1,y2)`, or `canvas.create_polygon(with parameters)`, nothing gets printed on the canvas.

So, rectangles are printed, but ovals and polygons not.

I have some more news about: I ran the same program in a Virtual Machine with Windows 7, and all commands work as they should.

Does somebody have the same experience? I searched, but couldn't find anything.

I read that sometimes on a Mac, colors don't get presented. Is this something similar?

Here goes the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
from tkinter import* 
root=Tk() canvas=Canvas(root,width=1200,height=800,bg="lightblue",bd=0,highlightthickness=0) 
canvas.pack() 


balk1=canvas.create_rectangle(400,320,480,360, fill="black") 

circel1=canvas.create_oval(600,400,800,600, fill="black") mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, are you providing explicit colors, or relying on defaults? Your short examples don't show any colors.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=1200,height=800,bg="lightblue",bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
balk1=canvas.create_rectangle(400,320,480,360, fill="black")
circel1=canvas.create_oval(600,400,800,600, fill="black")
mainloop()

Comment: When I execute this code, balk1 is printed correct on the canvas. Circel1 is NOT

Comment: Please don’t post code in the comments. You can [edit] your question to included requested information.